# Cassandra - Best table modelling for following query?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I wish to execute the following query:

> `SELECT value,occurredAt,venueName  FROM Transaction_by_card WHERE card = 1234123412341234`

and expect a few hundred results for each card, as is your regular credit card bill.

I was thinking about modelling the table like:

> (card int, occurredAt timestamp, venueName text, value int PRIMARY KEY (card,timestamp) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY occurredAt desc)

Is that the best model for my use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well just make sure that your total records per card should be less than 100 mb (kind of thumb rule in Cassandra) but i would prefer much less value than this.

If you assume that your result size can be more you can do time based baucketing
For example a month based bucket will look like

```
(card int, occurredAt timestamp, year int, month int, venueName text, value int PRIMARY KEY ( (card, year, month) timestamp) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY occurredAt desc)
```

month:04 and year 2020 will be derived from occurredAt  timstampp.